# SQL- Pad the value to provide result regardless of any number of leading zeros

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, padding

I am creating a SSRS report where my report input parameter will be AccountNumber where the user will input values which might have leading zeros.

I want to pad the account number for example:

In case, the user enters the value for AccountNumber: `00053216`

but the system should look for the AccountNumber: `53216`

and give the results regardless of leading zeros
or if the user enters the value: `522`,

the system should look for account number: `00522`

Could you please suggest what do we need to use for this situation?
Please note that there can be any number of leading zeros with Account Number.

Answer (score 3):

Leading zeros are ignored if you convert the value to integer:

`=CInt(Parameters!AccountNumber.Value)`

Comment: I'm glad this worked out for you.  Please remember you also have the option to accept a helpful answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use RIGHT(). just make sure you have at least 5 character in your parameter by adding extra zeros to the front

```
SELECT RIGHT('00000' + @AccountNumber, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more elegant solution but this works...

```
declare @input as varchar(10)
Set @input = ' 00053216'

Select Right(case len(@input) when 2 then '000'+@input
when 3 then '00'+@input when 4 then '0'+@input else @input end,5)

Set @input = '522'
Select Right(case len(@input) when 2 then '000'+@input
when 3 then '00'+@input when 4 then '0'+@input else @input end,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  RIGHT('00000' + CAST( CAST(AccountNumber AS INT) AS VARCHAR(5)) , 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simpler solution can be handle the user input at T-SQL level. However in SSRS you can use two parameters for correcting user inputs.

In addition to the paramater you already have, create another parameter called ActualAccount and set it as `internal`.

In default values go to add values and set the below expression referencing the parameter `AccountNumber` (user input) value.

```
=Right("00000" & Parameters!AccountNumber.Value,5)
```

Pass @ActualAccount to the query you want to use the parameter, note `@AccountNumber` will be the user input but the actual value for filtering your query will be `@ActualAccount`.